# Updating a value after line execution (Similar to var++)

Tags: c#

I was wondering if was possible to update a value AFTER the line excutes, similar to:

```
int age = 10;
Console.WriteLine(age++);
```

outputs 10, but `age` becomes 11 right after.

My goal is to have something like:

```
int offset = 1;
Console.WriteLine(offset += 4);
```

But having the aforementioned behavior.

Edit: I know that you can always do it in 2 lines, but I was wondering / hoping you could do it in one.

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Any particular reason for trying to keep it to one line? In practice, complicated to understand one-liners are usually shunned in favor of more readable/maintainable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the value after calling the function:

```
int offset = 1;
Console.WriteLine(offset);
offset += 4;
```

You see:

```
Console.WriteLine(age++);
```

Is in essence the same as:

```
Console.WriteLine(age);
age += 1;
```

Comment: +1 cool solution... never would have thought of posting this for real :-)

Comment: so there's no way to do it inline?

Comment: @Yahia - Looks like Robert Harvey had the same though ;-)

Comment: @Mike - No. There is no language support for it.

Comment: @Oded I see... gave him +1 too in hope that he won't try to kill anyone :-)

Comment: @Mike - Why try to get everything in one line? It can make for truly unreadable lines.

Comment: @oded learned a new word (mentch) - always like to learn something new :-)

Comment: the line itself isn't too long, plus there are a lot of lines in a row that would use it, so I was hoping to trim down all the extra lines. 

I agree that if I was working on a team project, or where anyone else would be using/reading it, separating the lines is a much better idea, but in this case it's only me, and for some reason having that small updating line right after makes me cringe a little.

Comment: @Mike; Stop cringing. One day you will look at your old code and cringe because you put it all on one line.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to make the developers who have to maintain your code later much happier if you just do it the old-fashioned way:

```
int offset = 1; 
Console.WriteLine(offset); 
offset += 4;
```

I'd kill the person who tried to inline this, and make me puzzle it out.  Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you are unable to overload the ++ operator on integers to achieve the result that you want. You also cannot nest the ++ operator to post increment multiple times.
A similar question was asked here:

[C/C++ Post-increment by more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360627/c-c-post-increment-by-more-than-one)

The general consensus is that you just have to use the extra line, and write

```
Console.WriteLine(offset);
offset += 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you cheat.

I recommend against it for general style and good sense purposes; but it is possible to combine all that into one line:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", offset, offset += 4);
```